# Matplotlib subplots with a single row

Tags: python, matplotlib

When we consider a call to `plt.subplots()` with a 2x2 grid:

```
def pltpoc():
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,10)
  y = np.sin(x)
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
  axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
  axs[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0]')
  axs[0, 1].plot(x, y, 'tab:orange')
  axs[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1]')
  axs[1, 0].plot(x, -y, 'tab:green')
  axs[1, 0].set_title('Axis [1,0]')
  axs[1, 1].plot(x, -y, 'tab:red')
  axs[1, 1].set_title('Axis [1,1]')
  plt.show()

pltpoc()
```

Things look swell:

[image]

There seems to be a different behavior for the `axes` returned by `plt.subplots()` when the number of rows is only 1. Consider this updated code with the only difference that it has one row not two:

```
def pltpoc1():
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,10)
  y = np.sin(x)
  fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2)
  axs[0, 0].plot(x, y)
  axs[0, 0].set_title('Axis [0,0]')
  axs[0, 1].plot(x, y, 'tab:orange')
  axs[0, 1].set_title('Axis [0,1]')
  plt.show()

pltpoc1()
```

Now we have a *completely different* behavior:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "<ipython-input-3-434adc6ec1d8>", line 1, in <module>
    pltpoc1()   File "<ipython-input-2-3b01fe0b14d2>", line 6, in pltpoc1
    axs[0, 0].plot(x, y) IndexError: too many indices for array
```

So .. why is *one* row "special" ?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'd argue my question is more concise and clear on this specific issue of squeeze / one row.

Comment: From the other question your answer is spot-on about _squeeze_ : no debate on the value of your answer.

Comment: Your question is indeed (IMHO) a little bit different than the one pointed, but you'll find the answer inside. You have to set the parameter `squeeze`to `False`, `squeeze=False`.